# .Net 3.5 Windows Forms Application: x86 vs x64 load times on 64 bit Vista

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, windows-vista, 64-bit

We are developing a Winforms application and in the process of optimizing the start-up time.

The app runs on 64 bit Vista machines.  In our testing we found what seems like a counter intuitive result. All else equal, targeting 32-bit vs 64-bit loads in half the time.  Can anyone shed some light as to why?

Thanks.

[Edit]
We deploy the app via ClickOnce which, from our research starts apps in a unique sandbox.  Therefore it always cold-starts so looking to improve performance here was fruitless.

Our main problem was the existence of 32-bit dlls in the project.  Once we targeted the project at x86 (even though it runs on x64) the load times were cut in half. 
[/Edit]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 3.5 SP1 gets its improved startup perf by no longer verifying the strong name of assemblies that come from trusted locations.  A bit controversial in my book but somewhat defensible.

I did check if the 64-bit version of the CLR also bypasses that time-consuming step.  Signed a DLL, put it in the GAC, then patched a byte.  No complaints when loading the assembly.  So it is not the SP1 startup pref improvement that explains the difference.

Other factors in the startup time are:
- Loading the CLR from disk (coldstart only)
- Groveling for the dependent assemblies
- JIT compiling the startup code

Coldstart could well be a factor, you probably don't have other processes running that have the 64-bit version of the CLR loaded.  Easy to eliminate by running a dummy .NET app while you do the test.

Groveling assemblies could take longer for the same reason.  It is unlikely that the 64-bit ngen-ed images of the .NET assemblies are in the file system cache.  Again, easy to eliminate with the dummy app having a dependency on the same assemblies.

The 64-bit JITter is a tougher nut to crack.  An arbitrary call is to assume that MSFT didn't spend as much time making that one performant as the 32-bit JITter.  Nothing backed-up by any evidence though.  Difficult to measure too, you'd have load an assembly with Assembly.Load, then time Activator.CreateInstance() where the class constructor calls as much code as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The 64-bit version would typically use twice as much memory on the heap: each pointer takes twice as much space, and .NET is full of pointers. As startup heavily influenced by memory initialization, this may account for part of the additional overhead. Refer also [Donald Knuth's flame about 64-bit pointers](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/news08.html).

Answer (score 1):

Note that according to Microsoft, .Net 3.5 SP1 included a fair bit of work on startup performance (up to a 40% improvement for some apps), so you might see if that helps at all as well.